# learning OOP, what's wrong?

Tags: php, class, oop

I can't get why the Exception always fires when the value of `$lf` is 1 or 2.

```
class Demo {
    public function __construct($lv) {
        if ($lv != 1 || $lv != 2) {
            throw new Exception('Wrong access level!');
        }    
    }

    $objDemo = new Demo(1);
```

What I want is for an exception to be thrown if the value of `$lv` isn't 1 or 2.

Comment: Your logic is wrong, think about it: `IF $lv is not 1 OR is not 2, throw exception`. Means if `$lv` is 1, it's not 2 -> throw exception. Means if `$lv` is 2, it's not 1 -> throw exception.

Comment: So, whatever integer you put the `if` will always be satisfied and exception will be thrown.

Comment: if 1 != 1 OR 1 != 2 ... Think about it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is not OOP-related.

You're passing the value of 1 into your `$lv` variable. That makes for the following situation:

```
$lv = 1;

if ( $lv != 1 || $lv != 2 ){
    throw new Exception('Wrong access level!');
}
```

We can separate what's in the if statement:

- The first expression (`$lv != 1`) will be evaluated to false because 1 does equal 1.
- The second expression (`$lv != 2`) will be evaluated to true because 1 does not equal 2.

In this case:

```
false || true
```

Evaluates to true.

What you want instead is to change the or operator to an and operator:

```
if ( $lv != 1 && $lv != 2 ){
    throw new Exception('Wrong access level!');
}
```

Or, equivalently:

```
if ( !( $lv == 1 || $lv == 2 )){
    throw new Exception('Wrong access level!');
}
```

Comment: ahh, I understood my mistake... human's logic, tho) But how can I do what i want then? (without creating hundreds of IF-s)

Comment: @AndrewBro It's unclear what you want. What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: I wanna check if $lv not equals from 1 to 2 = throw E, if Lv is IN RANGE (1-2) - it's ok, do nothing/

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `($lv!=1 || $lv !=2)` is always true...every number is either not 1 or not 2.  It could be you want `($lv !=1 && $lv !=2)` instead.  But your requirements aren't clear so it could be something else.